# Django login doesn't work

Tags: django, authentication

I tried to create a login view like the following:

```
def user_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        if user:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('rango/index.html')
            else:
                return HttpResponse('Your Rango account is disabled!')
        else:
            print("Invalid login details: {0}, {1}".format(username, password))
            return HttpResponse("Invalid login details supplied!")
    else:
        return render(request, 'rango/login.html', {})
```

This seems to be the correct way to do so, but when I try to open the page in my browser, I get the following error:

```
TypeError at /rango/login/
login() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/rango/login/

Django Version: 1.9.10
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
login() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user'
Exception Location: C:\Users\Johannes\tangowithdjango\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in get_response, line 147
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Johannes\tangowithdjango\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.6.0
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\Johannes\\tangowithdjango\\tango_with_django_project',
 'C:\\Users\\Johannes\\tangowithdjango\\Scripts\\python36.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\Johannes\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\Johannes\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\Johannes\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36',
 'C:\\Users\\Johannes\\tangowithdjango',
 'C:\\Users\\Johannes\\tangowithdjango\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 12 Jan 2017 17:56:38 +0100
```

Has anyone encountered something similar or knows a solution to the problem? I already searched and tried around for a bit but couldn't find an answer.

Comment: The error doesn't seem to be coming from this code. Regardless, please can you set DEBUG to True, and then show the full traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks good, make sure that you are importing this

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
```

Also check your views
This is the first url:

```
url(r'^login', example_views.login, name='log'),
```

And you have to change to this:

```
url(r'^log', example_views.log, name='log'),
```

Answer (score 0):

I followed that tutorial and came across the same error.

I solved it by correcting one line in *urls.py*

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    ...
    url(r'^login/$', views.login, name='login'),
)
```

into this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    ...
    url(r'^login/$', views.user_login, name='login'),
)
```

It should be the name of the login view you created, which is 'user_login' in your case.